# `rlang::exec` fails with `WRS2::rmmcp`

Tags: r, rlang

I have never had issues with `rlang::exec`, but it mysteriously seems to fail with `WRS2::rmmcp` and I am not sure why or how to solve it.

```r
# setup
set.seed(123)
library(WRS2)
library(rlang)

# works
WRS2::rmmcp(
  y = WineTasting$Taste,
  groups = WineTasting$Wine,
  blocks = WineTasting$Taster
)
#> Call:
#> WRS2::rmmcp(y = WineTasting$Taste, groups = WineTasting$Wine, 
#>     blocks = WineTasting$Taster)
#> 
#>                    psihat ci.lower ci.upper p.value p.crit   sig
#> Wine A vs. Wine B 0.02143 -0.02164  0.06449 0.19500 0.0500 FALSE
#> Wine A vs. Wine C 0.11429  0.02148  0.20710 0.00492 0.0169  TRUE
#> Wine B vs. Wine C 0.08214  0.00891  0.15538 0.00878 0.0250  TRUE

# doesn't work
rlang::exec(
  .fn = WRS2::rmmcp,
  y = WineTasting$Taste,
  groups = WineTasting$Wine,
  blocks = WineTasting$Taster
)
#> Error in names(x) <- value: 'names' attribute [18] must be the same length as the vector [3]
```

Why does this fail and how to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One alternative to `exec` is to construct the call by hand and then evaluate it:

```
mycall <- rlang::call2( "rmmcp", .ns="WRS2",
                       y = quote(WineTasting$Taste),
                       groups = quote(WineTasting$Wine),
                       blocks = quote(WineTasting$Taster) )
# WRS2::rmmcp(y = WineTasting$Taste, groups = WineTasting$Wine,
#     blocks = WineTasting$Taster)

eval(mycall)   # Works
```

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the source code of `WRS2::rmmcp` the first few rows shows the cause of the error.

```
WRS2::rmmcp

function (y, groups, blocks, tr = 0.2, alpha = 0.05) 
{
    cols1 <- deparse(substitute(y))
    cols2 <- deparse(substitute(groups))
    cols3 <- deparse(substitute(blocks))
    dat <- data.frame(y, groups, blocks)
    colnames(dat) <- c(cols1, cols2, cols3)
    #...
    #...
}
```

`deparse(substitute())` code does not work as expected when used with `rlang::exec`. We could hardcode the column names to make this work with `rlang::exec`.

```
tmp <- function (y, groups, blocks, tr = 0.2, alpha = 0.05) 
{
  cols1 <- 'col1' #Change
  cols2 <- 'col2' #Change
  cols3 <- 'col3' #Change
  dat <- data.frame(y, groups, blocks)
  colnames(dat) <- c(cols1, cols2, cols3)
  cl <- match.call()
  x <- reshape(dat, idvar = cols3, timevar = cols2, direction = "wide")[-1]
  grp <- c(1:length(x))
  con = 0
  dif = TRUE
  flagcon = F
  if (!is.matrix(x)) 
    x <- matl(x)
  if (!is.matrix(x)) 
    stop("Data must be stored in a matrix or in list mode.")
  con <- as.matrix(con)
  J <- ncol(x)
  xbar <- vector("numeric", J)
  x <- elimna(x)
  nval <- nrow(x)
  h1 <- nrow(x) - 2 * floor(tr * nrow(x))
  df <- h1 - 1
  for (j in 1:J) xbar[j] <- mean(x[, j], tr)
  if (sum(con^2 != 0)) 
    CC <- ncol(con)
  if (sum(con^2) == 0) 
    CC <- (J^2 - J)/2
  ncon <- CC
  if (alpha == 0.05) {
    dvec <- c(0.05, 0.025, 0.0169, 0.0127, 0.0102, 0.00851, 
              0.0073, 0.00639, 0.00568, 0.00511)
    if (ncon > 10) {
      avec <- 0.05/c(11:ncon)
      dvec <- c(dvec, avec)
    }
  }
  if (alpha == 0.01) {
    dvec <- c(0.01, 0.005, 0.00334, 0.00251, 0.00201, 0.00167, 
              0.00143, 0.00126, 0.00112, 0.00101)
    if (ncon > 10) {
      avec <- 0.01/c(11:ncon)
      dvec <- c(dvec, avec)
    }
  }
  if (alpha != 0.05 && alpha != 0.01) 
    dvec <- alpha/c(1:ncon)
  if (sum(con^2) == 0) {
    flagcon <- T
    psihat <- matrix(0, CC, 5)
    dimnames(psihat) <- list(NULL, c("Group", "Group", "psihat", 
                                     "ci.lower", "ci.upper"))
    test <- matrix(NA, CC, 6)
    dimnames(test) <- list(NULL, c("Group", "Group", "test", 
                                   "p.value", "p.crit", "se"))
    temp1 <- 0
    jcom <- 0
    for (j in 1:J) {
      for (k in 1:J) {
        if (j < k) {
          jcom <- jcom + 1
          q1 <- (nrow(x) - 1) * winvar(x[, j], tr)
          q2 <- (nrow(x) - 1) * winvar(x[, k], tr)
          q3 <- (nrow(x) - 1) * wincor(x[, j], x[, k], 
                                       tr)$cov
          sejk <- sqrt((q1 + q2 - 2 * q3)/(h1 * (h1 - 
                                                   1)))
          if (!dif) {
            test[jcom, 6] <- sejk
            test[jcom, 3] <- (xbar[j] - xbar[k])/sejk
            temp1[jcom] <- 2 * (1 - pt(abs(test[jcom, 
                                                3]), df))
            test[jcom, 4] <- temp1[jcom]
            psihat[jcom, 1] <- j
            psihat[jcom, 2] <- k
            test[jcom, 1] <- j
            test[jcom, 2] <- k
            psihat[jcom, 3] <- (xbar[j] - xbar[k])
          }
          if (dif) {
            dv <- x[, j] - x[, k]
            test[jcom, 6] <- trimse(dv, tr)
            temp <- trimci(dv, alpha = alpha/CC, pr = FALSE, 
                           tr = tr)
            test[jcom, 3] <- temp$test.stat
            temp1[jcom] <- temp$p.value
            test[jcom, 4] <- temp1[jcom]
            psihat[jcom, 1] <- j
            psihat[jcom, 2] <- k
            test[jcom, 1] <- j
            test[jcom, 2] <- k
            psihat[jcom, 3] <- mean(dv, tr = tr)
            psihat[jcom, 4] <- temp$ci[1]
            psihat[jcom, 5] <- temp$ci[2]
          }
        }
      }
    }
    temp2 <- order(0 - temp1)
    zvec <- dvec[1:ncon]
    sigvec <- (test[temp2] >= zvec)
    if (sum(sigvec) < ncon) {
      dd <- ncon - sum(sigvec)
      ddd <- sum(sigvec) + 1
      zvec[ddd:ncon] <- dvec[ddd]
    }
    test[temp2, 5] <- zvec
    if (!dif) {
      psihat[, 4] <- psihat[, 3] - qt(1 - alpha/(2 * CC), 
                                      df) * test[, 6]
      psihat[, 5] <- psihat[, 3] + qt(1 - alpha/(2 * CC), 
                                      df) * test[, 6]
    }
  }
  if (sum(con^2) > 0) {
    if (nrow(con) != ncol(x)) 
      warning("The number of groups does not match the number of contrast coefficients.")
    ncon <- ncol(con)
    psihat <- matrix(0, ncol(con), 4)
    dimnames(psihat) <- list(NULL, c("con.num", "psihat", 
                                     "ci.lower", "ci.upper"))
    test <- matrix(0, ncol(con), 5)
    dimnames(test) <- list(NULL, c("con.num", "test", "p.value", 
                                   "p.crit", "se"))
    temp1 <- NA
    for (d in 1:ncol(con)) {
      psihat[d, 1] <- d
      if (!dif) {
        psihat[d, 2] <- sum(con[, d] * xbar)
        sejk <- 0
        for (j in 1:J) {
          for (k in 1:J) {
            djk <- (nval - 1) * wincor(x[, j], x[, k], 
                                       tr)$cov/(h1 * (h1 - 1))
            sejk <- sejk + con[j, d] * con[k, d] * djk
          }
        }
        sejk <- sqrt(sejk)
        test[d, 1] <- d
        test[d, 2] <- sum(con[, d] * xbar)/sejk
        test[d, 5] <- sejk
        temp1[d] <- 2 * (1 - pt(abs(test[d, 2]), df))
      }
      if (dif) {
        for (j in 1:J) {
          if (j == 1) 
            dval <- con[j, d] * x[, j]
          if (j > 1) 
            dval <- dval + con[j, d] * x[, j]
        }
        temp1[d] <- trimci(dval, tr = tr, pr = FALSE)$p.value
        test[d, 1] <- d
        test[d, 2] <- trimci(dval, tr = tr, pr = FALSE)$test.stat
        test[d, 5] <- trimse(dval, tr = tr)
        psihat[d, 2] <- mean(dval, tr = tr)
      }
    }
    test[, 3] <- temp1
    temp2 <- order(0 - temp1)
    zvec <- dvec[1:ncon]
    sigvec <- (test[temp2, 3] >= zvec)
    if (sum(sigvec) < ncon) {
      dd <- ncon - sum(sigvec)
      ddd <- sum(sigvec) + 1
    }
    test[temp2, 4] <- zvec
    psihat[, 3] <- psihat[, 2] - qt(1 - test[, 4]/2, df) * 
      test[, 5]
    psihat[, 4] <- psihat[, 2] + qt(1 - test[, 4]/2, df) * 
      test[, 5]
  }
  if (flagcon) 
    num.sig <- sum(test[, 4] <= test[, 5])
  if (!flagcon) 
    num.sig <- sum(test[, 3] <= test[, 4])
  fnames <- as.character(unique(groups))
  psihat1 <- cbind(psihat, test[, 4:5])
  result <- list(comp = psihat1, fnames = fnames, call = cl)
  class(result) <- "mcp2"
  result
}
```

Note that I have copied the entire code just for the sake of reproducibility, the change in this function is only 1st 3 lines.

After you run the function you can use it as :

```
tmp(
  y = WineTasting$Taste,
  groups = WineTasting$Wine,
  blocks = WineTasting$Taster
)

#Call:
#tmp(y = WineTasting$Taste, groups = WineTasting$Wine, blocks = WineTasting$Taster)

#                   psihat ci.lower ci.upper p.value p.crit   sig
#Wine A vs. Wine B 0.02143 -0.02164  0.06449 0.19500 0.0500 FALSE
#Wine A vs. Wine C 0.11429  0.02148  0.20710 0.00492 0.0169  TRUE
#Wine B vs. Wine C 0.08214  0.00891  0.15538 0.00878 0.0250  TRUE
```

And with `rlang::exec`

```
res <- rlang::exec(
  .fn = tmp,
  y = WineTasting$Taste,
  groups = WineTasting$Wine,
  blocks = WineTasting$Taster
) 

res$comp
#     Group Group     psihat     ci.lower   ci.upper     p.value p.crit
#[1,]     1     2 0.02142857 -0.021636832 0.06449397 0.195004531 0.0500
#[2,]     1     3 0.11428571  0.021475579 0.20709585 0.004915566 0.0169
#[3,]     2     3 0.08214286  0.008910564 0.15537515 0.008777396 0.0250

res$fnames
#[1] "Wine A" "Wine B" "Wine C"
```

(although using it with `rlang::exec` spoils `res$call`. Don't know why!)

While running this I got errors like `could not find function elimna` or `could not find function matl` which is strange since those functions are from package `WRS2` which I had loaded but still it gave the error. I had to copy the functions from https://github.com/cran/WRS2/tree/master/R into my session after which it worked as shown above.

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't solve my problem though. I can't copy and modify a package function. I am looking for a solution that wouldn't involve changing the original function. If this is an unexpected behavior from `rlang`, then that would also be useful to know because then I can file a bug report.

Comment: I don't this is a bug in `rlang`. It should be reported as bug in `WRS2` package.